# Close process on Terminal server (Windows 2008, x64)

Tags: process, windows-server-2008, autohotkey

Need some help on the *process close* function under the **Windows Sever 2008 (x64)**.
When I run this code on Win7 (x64), it kills process perfectly, but when I run it under the terminal user session (W2k8, x64), it detects the process of other users and off cource, can't close it. How can I fix it? Any ideas?

Script code:

```
check:
{
Process, Exist, name.exe
Msgbox,ErrorLevel: %ErrorLevel%
NewID = %ErrorLevel%
Msgbox,ErrLev: %ErrorLevel% / NewID: %NewID%
if NewID = 0
{
      Msgbox, Nothing to close ;)
      return
}
else
{
      {
  Sleep, 500
      Msgbox, Something seems to be opened...
      Process, Close, name.exe
      Msgbox,Closed(ErrLev=%ErrorLevel%) (NewID=%NewID%)
      Sleep, 100
      Goto, check
      }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you want? a) Closing ALL processes with that name (yours and those processes owned by others). b) Only find "your" processes and kill those then stop (b.t.w. can you activate these processes?).

Comment: I want to close only processes name.exe opened under my current user and then stop script. What do you mean "activate"? They're "stuck" in memory after some software was closed and to make it work after the next launch I need to kill all my opened(hidden) name.exe processes.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the UserName via AutoHotKey looks to be difficult, why not just use PowerShell (and maybe launch via AutoHotKey).

Here are two examples:

[Process Owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670466/check-for-process-owner-on-remote-machine-and-kill-it-when-owner-is-xyz)
[Process Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265869/kill-process-by-filename/10265997#10265997)