# Kill processes run by a specified user in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, process, kill

How can I kill all processes with the same name running by a specified user?

For example, I could have multiple *program.exe*'s running by different users. I could use:

```
get-process program.exe | kill
```

to kill all of them. But I just want to kill those instances run by a specified user. Is there a convenient way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for process owner on remote machine and kill it when owner is xyz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670466/check-for-process-owner-on-remote-machine-and-kill-it-when-owner-is-xyz)

Comment: From [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx) _Because the System.Diagnostics.Process object that Get-Process returns does not have a property or method that returns the process owner, the command uses
the Get-WmiObject cmdlet to get a Win32_Process object that represents the same process._

Comment: @ssnobody, thanks, exact what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
TASKKILL.EXE /FI "USERNAME eq walid" /IM myprog.exe
```

You can also use wildcards:

```
TASKKILL.EXE /FI "USERNAME eq w*" /IM m*
```

For more details type: `taskkill.exe /?`

Comment: To be honest, I now like this better!

Comment: To make idempotent, you can check that the process is running as that user with: `"(Get-Process myprog.exe -IncludeUserName ).UserName -eq 'foobar'"`

Answer (score 9):

V5 users can do this:

```
Get-Process program.exe -IncludeUserName | Where UserName -match joe | Stop-Process
```

The `-IncludeUserName` parameter requires that you are in an elevated console.

Comment: Good to know that, nice and simple.